# How to add anything in <head> through jquery/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

I'm working with a CMS, which prevents editing HTML source for `<head>` element.

For example I want to add the following above the `<title>` tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
```

Comment: This doesn't make sence... The head is parsed prior to the execution of javascript. Adding meta stuf to the head via javascript would not have the desired effect.

Comment: @Mickel - yes. answers of all questions helps me

Comment: While not related to the CMS question, it can make sense to add meta tags in certain circumstances. There are various browser addons and javascript injections that use data that is in the meta tags to gather information. Facebook's OpenGraph is one example. Injecting meta tags into the head is needed when you don't have direct access to the originating HTML, whether by fault of a CMS or because you are writing a javascript addon/injection yourself.

Comment: Note that it's possible that adding `<meta>` tags dynamically will have no effect, depending on what they are and what browser is involved.

Comment: Good point, that's what happens when one focuses too much on the problem ;-)

Comment: @AndreHaverdings It makes sense if you're trying to dynamically add a canonical url for web crawlers using something like Phantom JS, or you have something that parses your DOM other than the browser. Either way, that's not an answer to OP's question. Save that attitude for IRC.

Answer (score 173, accepted):

You can select it and add to it as normal:

```
$('head').append('<link />');
```

Comment: how can i control order , where this link will be placed

Comment: Read the documentation: http://docs.jquery.com/Manipulation `insertBefore`, `insertAfter` is what you want.

Comment: I have put this in document.ready, but it doesn't append to my head contents

Comment: It is adding link, but link not showing in page's view Source... I can view it from browser development tools like Firebug. Can I view link in view source also?

Comment: @PankajTiwari You won't see it in the source view because the code appends it to the current document, not the original source (which was provided by the server). That's why FireBug and Chrome Dev tools are so useful.

Comment: i couddn't find the attached html using firebug or chrome dev tools. how to know whether its appended or not.

Comment: @PankajTiwari Newer Firefox versions have build in dev tools. Just hit [ctrl+shift+k] (if you didn't change shortcuts) and choose inspector. If javascript change html source, it will be highlighted for some moment.

Comment: How would I append an html string? I am provided this html dynamically and don't know the structure of it ahead of time to convert it to an html element

Comment: If you're sure the content is safe (ie: not from user input), maybe it'd work to put the content into a temporary element and then move elements into the head:
```
const tmp = document.createElement('div');
tmp.innerHTML = theStringOfDefinitelySafeHTML;
for (const el of [...tmp.children]) document.head.appendChild(el);
```

Answer (score 158):

JavaScript:

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild( ... );
```

Make DOM element like so:

```js
const link = document.createElement('link');
link.href = 'href';
link.rel = 'rel';

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
```

Comment: Works with script elements!

Answer (score 33):

jQuery

```
$('head').append( ... );
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild( ... );
```

Comment: dosen't appendChild require a DOM-element? ie. var elem = document.createElement() document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild( elem );

Comment: well yes. i just left that part as `...` because i didn't feel that was a central part of the question, and also, at the time of writing, there was no hands-on example as to what he wanted to put in head. but yes, it does need to be a DOM-element.

Answer (score 17):

You can use `innerHTML` to just concat the extra field string;

```
document.head.innerHTML = document.head.innerHTML + '<link rel="stylesheet>...'
```

However, you can't guarantee that the extra things you add to the head will be recognised by the browser after the first load, and it's possible you will get a FOUC (flash of unstyled content) as the extra stylesheets are loaded.

I haven't looked at the API in years, but you could also use [`document.write`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write), which is what was designed for this sort of action. However, this would require you to block the page from rendering until your initial AJAX request has completed.

Comment: You can also use ```document.head.innerHTML +=  '<link rel="stylesheet>...'```
 Just Short of your Code

Answer (score 12):

Create a temporary element (e. g. `DIV`), assign your HTML code to its `innerHTML` property, and then append its *child nodes* to the `HEAD` element one by one. For example, like this:

```js
var temp = document.createElement('div');

temp.innerHTML = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="example.css" />'
               + '<script src="foobar.js"><\/script> ';

var head = document.head;

while (temp.firstChild) {
    head.appendChild(temp.firstChild);
}
```

Compared with rewriting entire `HEAD` contents via its `innerHTML`, this wouldn’t affect existing child elements of the `HEAD` element in any way.

Note that *scripts* inserted this way are apparently not executed automatically, while styles are applied successfully. So if you need scripts to be executed, you should load JS files using [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) and then execute their contents using [`eval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval).

Comment: That is how I do it in the `body`, but can that really be done inside the `head`-tag? I was under the impression that the only allowed tags where `base`, `link`, `meta`, `title`, `style` and `script`?

Comment: AFAICT, you have exactly those elements in your Ajax response. Don't you?

Comment: Indeed, but I still can't make it work with a div inside the head tag. It seems like Chrome is "smart" enough to display the content of the div in the body anyway.

Comment: You've probably not read the answer carefully. ;-) The `DIV` element is just a temporary container for the purpose of _parsing HTML code_. You shouldn't insert the `DIV` itself to the `HEAD`. You should insert its _child nodes_. Please see the example I've added to the answer.

Comment: What does while (temp.firstChild) ? (sorry about the necropost)

Comment: @GaetanL. “While there are child elements inside the `temp` element.” See [Node.firstChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild) docs.

Answer (score 11):

In the latest browsers (IE9+) you can also use [document.head](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.head):

**Example:**

```
var favicon = document.createElement('link');
favicon.id = 'myFavicon';
favicon.rel = 'shortcut icon';
favicon.href = 'http://www.test.com/my-favicon.ico';

document.head.appendChild(favicon);
```

Answer (score 5):

**Try a javascript pure:**

Library JS:

```
appendHtml = function(element, html) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = html;
    while (div.children.length > 0) {
        element.appendChild(div.children[0]);
    }
}
```

Type:
`appendHtml(document.head, '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://example.com/example.css"/>');`

**or jQuery:**

```
$('head').append($('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />').attr('href', 'http://example.com/example.css'));
```

Answer (score -6):

With jquery you have other option:

```
$('head').html($('head').html() + '...');
```

anyway it is working. JavaScript option others said, thats correct too.

Comment: That will delete the existing content and generate new elements. This can have undesirable side effects such as losing dynamically set DOM properties and causing scripts to be re-executed.

Comment: for this reason you should use before $('head').html() to recover all the DOM properties

Comment: Using `.html()` won't recover **all** the DOM properties. (The most common instance of this problem, and the most visible, is when using similar code to add new fields to a form. The value attribute represents the default value of a field, so getting `html()` and then setting it back will reset all the existing fields to their default values).

Comment: I can sure you I tested it in my code and it is working and all the DOM properties Works. Please, test yourself, I am working IE11

Comment: Things that may be removed are events also.