# Javascript how to use external Css sheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
   var mynewhtml = 
                  + '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>'
                  + '<div id="tabs">'
                  +  '<ul>'
                  +  '<li><a href="#tabs-1">Tab 1</a></li>'
                  +  '<li><a href="#tabs-2">Tab 2</a></li>'
                  +  '<li><a href="#tabs-3">Tab 3</a></li>'
                  +  '</ul>'
                  +  '<div id="tabs-1">'
                  + '<p>Lalalala</p>'
                  +  '</div>'
                  +  '<div id="tabs-2">'  
                  +  '</div>'
                  +  '<div id="tabs-3">'
                  +  '</div>'
                  + '</div>'

 $(mynewhtml).appendTo("body");
```

So I have a wegpage, but I can't alter the html, I can only add html via Jquery/javascript. Adding the html isn't a problem, but how can I use an external style sheet to set the style of my newly added html?

Thank you.

Comment: you can write a chrome extension if you are using chrome.

Comment: Why can you not edit the `html` but you can edit the `javascript`?

Comment: I'm making a userscript. So i can't alter thehtml file itself but I can alter the html via javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this

```
$('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>');
```

Comment: I now have <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/> in my head, but my list stays a normal list while it should be this : http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#default

Answer (score 0):

For detailed explination you can refer this thread as well.

[how to add anything in <head> through jquery/javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900874/how-to-add-anything-in-head-through-jquery-javascript)