# jQuery(document.head).append won't print my code in the head

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have been given the task of working with a CMS and I dont have access to the  to put CSS and a meta tag. Im using the following that renders ok but when I look at the source the style and meta tags are not printed in the .

Please help and help appreciated - Matt

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

jQuery(document.head).append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-     scale=1/>');

jQuery(document.head).append('<link rel="stylesheet"href="css/main.css" type="text/css" />');

</script>
```

Comment: Are you using 'View Source' to see the HTML, or a DOM viewer such as Dev tools or firebug? You need to use the latter as it shows the current state of the DOM. The former only shows the HTML in the state it was loaded, ie. before you appended anything to the `head`. Also, you may need a document ready handler, unless this script is run at the end of the `body`.

Comment: Does this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900874/how-to-add-anything-in-head-through-jquery-javascript

Comment: somethink like that doesn't work ? $('head').append('<link />');

Comment: Rory McCrossan thanks Thats the reason. its always the simple things.

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jQuery('head').append('<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1/>');
    jQuery('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet"href="css/main.css" type="text/css" />');
</script>
```

Comment: This should be an edit to the original question, not an answer.