# Angular 2 component css position

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I want to load component css in a specific order. I've got this component :

```
@Component({
    selector: '[select2]',
    styleUrls: [
        "assets/plugins/select2/css/select2.min.css", 
        "assets/plugins/select2/css/select2-bootstrap.min.css"],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class Select2Component { }
```

and this is what I get, when I'm using it:

```
<head>
    <script src="angular.js"></script><!-- 2. Configure SystemJS-->
    <script src="base.js"></script>
    <script src="components.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/plugins/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- BEGIN GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES-->
    <link href="/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- END GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES-->
    <!-- BEGIN THEME GLOBAL STYLES-->
    <link href="/assets/css/global/plugins.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <!-- END THEME GLOBAL STYLES-->
    <script>System.import('boot').catch(console.error.bind(console));</script>
    <style> contents of "assets/plugins/select2/css/select2.min.css" </style>
    <style> contents of "assets/plugins/select2/css/select2-bootstrap.min.css"</style>
</head>
```

The question is, can I set position where to load component styles? In this case I want them to load right before `<!-- BEGIN THEME GLOBAL STYLES-->`, not at the end of the head, because my `plugins.css` overrides some `select2.css` rules.

The result would be:

```
...
<!-- END GLOBAL MANDATORY STYLES-->
<style> contents of "assets/plugins/select2/css/select2.min.css" </style>
<style> contents of "assets/plugins/select2/css/select2-bootstrap.min.css"</style>
<!-- BEGIN THEME GLOBAL STYLES-->
...
```

Comment: could you please expand on your issue, as currently I can't make any sense of your issue nor what you want.

Comment: @jbutler483 thanks for reply and I'm sorry for my unclear question. I've updated it.

Comment: The comment within [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1900880/3436942) may be able to point you in the right direction, if it is what I think you're trying to achieve

Comment: @jbutler483 That's right, I could use jquery's `insertBefore` and `insertAfter`, but is it possible to do that automatically for every component?