# Jquery - How to add <link> attribute into header with mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I do some experiments with prefetch and prerender. It's a fantastic extension! The problem is that I have many links on many listing pages in an online shop (item links, pagination, links to subcategories...). and I can't add all links into header for prefetching and prerendering. So, my idea is to add links  on the fly into header if user hover a link with mouse cursor. I tried this manually with chrome developer tool and it works. Chrome  is prefetching the link as soon as I have added the  attribute into header.

Does anynone know how to do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to add anything in <head> through jquery/javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900874/how-to-add-anything-in-head-through-jquery-javascript)

Comment: Combination of `mouseover` event and `$('head').append('<link />');` , have you tried it?

Comment: @lelio-faieta yes, it's similar, but not exactly the same.

Comment: @RobertBaumann what is exactly the difference? btw this is not a "write code on your behalf service" you know? What is your effort? What have you tried?

Comment: @kobe I know this combination and would be the solution, but I'm not really an expert. I need a code example. :(

Comment: @lelio-faieta my current solution is a smarty solution without jQuery or any other script. With smarty I can generate <link> attributes within <body>. It works, but too much requests at the same time and not really nice code within body instead of header. I need a solution (code example) to solve it with jQuery and on the fly with mouseover.

Comment: @RobertBaumann i made an example please test it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$( "#element" ).mouseover(function() {
    link=document.createElement('link');
    link.href='href';
    link.rel='rel';
    link.id ='linkid'; //you may save it for future purpose - like removing it, or check next time event happen if link already created so don't add it again.

    $('head').append(link);  //bring it to BOTTOM of head includes
});
```

if you want to add the new `link` to the TOP of head includes use:

```
$('head').prepend(link);
```

instead of

```
$('head').append(link);
```

**EDIT:**
Pure JavaScript version (just the first option- append to the bottom):

```
document.getElementById("demo").addEventListener("mouseover", addHeadStyle);
//Note: The addEventListener() method is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier versions.

function addHeadStyle() {
    link = document.createElement('link');
    link.href = 'href';
    link.rel = 'rel';
    link.id = 'linkid'; //you may save it for future purpose - like removing it, or check next time event happen if link already created so don't add it again.

    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(link);
};
```

Comment: It is working, yes, but I have a big handicap. I have optimized my page extremly. e.a. all scripts are placed at the bottom of the page, but your code must be placed within a template file for item listing to get single ID*s in a foreach loop. Therefore I get a reference error because jquery loads after your code.. Is there a workaround?

Comment: @RobertBaumann i've added pure js example, so you can use it without jQuery loaded.

Comment: It get ReferenceError: addHeadStyle is not defined

Comment: @RobertBaumann you right the function name was wrong, rename it to `addHeadStyle` or recopy

Comment: sorry, my mistake. It works now! <link> attribute will added to header if a link is hovered and all links will prefetched. Fantastic! BUT this happends every time a link is hovered. Can this be done only once?

Comment: @RobertBaumann add your logic in the function for achieving it.

Comment: I can do that, but my case it is very special and can't copy 1 to 1. your code is the base for any other and helps! My final solution is at the very top of website improvement and reduced load time up to 80%. prefetching and prerendering is only a part of many many modifications.

Comment: Conclusion: I get what I need and you my are my hero! :) Thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: @RobertBaumann I'm glad to know, please mark it as answer so other users will find it useful.