# Is there any difference between adding template tags to the head or body of an HTML doc?

Tags: html, html-templates

Is there any consideration that should be done between using the head or the body to add template tags? Ex:

```
conste template = document.createElement('template');
// add template content etc.

document.body.appendChild(template);
// or
document.head.appendChild(template);
```

I just stumble upon a code base that dynamically adds templates to `head` and my gut tells me that maybe it isn't the best idea, but maybe it doesn't matter?

Comment: I think you can only add stuff like script and link tags to the head, not html elements.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900874/how-to-add-anything-in-head-through-jquery-javascript

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Templates are among the most flexible of all the elements in where they can be placed. [The spec says](https://w3c.github.io/html/semantics-scripting.html#elementdef-template)

> Contexts in which this element can be used:
>     - Where metadata content is expected. 
>     - Where phrasing content is expected. 
>     - Where script-supporting elements are expected. 
>     - As a child of a colgroup element that doesn’t have a span attribute.

"Where metadata content is expected." essentially means in the head.

"Where phrasing content is expected." essentially means anywhere the valid child of a body element can go.

"Where script-supporting elements are expected" means it can go even in places that phrasing content can't, such as the child of ul, ol, table, tbody, tr etc elements.

Comment: Nice, then per [WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#the-template-element:concept-element-contexts), I can have templates as list-items and table-cells (if they are to populate their respective parents anyway).