# How to use *ngIf in index.html angular 8

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular8

How can I use *ngIf condition in `index.html` in Angular2+. I want to load tags based on condition using `*ngIf` for that I have a value in local storage. Here is my code but it is not working.

```
<head *ngIf="localStorage.getItem('theme_token') === 'site-layout'"></head
```

When I used script tag it get the value of theme token in javascript.

```
 <script>

        var _val = localStorage.getItem('theme_token'); /// This part is working returning me the value.

    </script>
```

> Note: I don't want to hide. I have to render it using `*ngIf`
>   condition.

Comment: You can take your index.html inside to app.component.html then you can use ngIf there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*ngIf wouldn't do the trick for you. *ngIf will work inside angular. Try this example may this helps. It worked with angular 8. In your app component.

```
    constructor() {

    if (localStorage.getItem('theme_token') === 'site-layout') {
        const temp = document.createElement('link');
        temp.innerHTML = '<link id="default-css" href="assets/somestyle.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">'
                       ;
        const head = document.head;
        while (temp.firstChild) {
            head.appendChild(temp.firstChild);
        }

       }
}
```

You can load according to your condition.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I am aware Angular application (most of them) has entry point of `<app-root></app-root>` where the application is bootstrapped, means from this point angular will come into the picture(memory) and then you have your routes, other components, angular stuff the way you have structured the application.

Now you want to use `*ngIf` in `index.html`, so point is where you will bind this `index.html` i.e. with which component to supply your `*ngIf` variable and even if you will just add `*ngIf='true'` it will be rendered as it is without any **effect** or **side-effect**

What you can do (possibly)

1. Try to do with plain JS  via `<scrip></script>` access DOM, change it the way you want
2. If you want to do with Angular only, then in `app.component.ts` in `ngOnInit` access the DOM and do it.

[image]

[image]

Browser doesn't know what it has to with `*ngIf`, It is the angular that knows the meaning of  `*ngIf` and this particular point angular not loaded yet

Comment: can you please example of both plain javascript and app.component.ts?

Comment: For JS, you can check this example [JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900874/how-to-add-anything-in-head-through-jquery-javascript#answer-8316885)
and for angular, you have to inject DOM, a wrapper around it, and then you will access `<head>` in angular way, but underneath the same work  is happening. The only reason for angular is if you are getting some values from API and than you have to update some `meta` tag OR `title` of the page  than you can go with that way of doing

Comment: Can you please provide a clear example on that. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can't use *ngIf outside . We have multiple ways to do the same in pure javascript. Go with vanila js for no side-effetcs.