# IN AEM, how can i take values from a component in the body section and write them in the head section of the html

Tags: java, seo, aem, sightly

So say you have a component that is being used in the body section of a page. I want to take specific values from the text fields of that component and write them to the  of the html file.

I have a tile list component, with a title text field and a description rich text field.

```
                            <div class="col box-title">${tileitems.properties.title @ context='html'}</div>
                            <div data-sly-test='${description}' class="col">
                                <p>${tileitems.properties.rte || tileitems.properties.description @ context='html'}</p>
                            </div>
```

How can I get the values that are authored into the component and write on the same page but to the head of the html.

do i need a java model for this ? any examples thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have (at least) two options:

1. Append the needed markup to `head` from your content component using JavaScript.
2. Create an Use Object (Java/Sling Model) and walk the descendants tree searching for the specific resource type and properties and expose the data you need. Use this to append the needed markup in the `head`.

Comment: so first the option, append with javascript. any examples, I do not think javascript will work since the page would of already by loaded.

Comment: @developers you can still append (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900874/how-to-add-anything-in-head-through-jquery-javascript). But it might not be as useful (for example meta tags might be intended for clients/scripts that ignore Javascript or process the head before the append is done).

Comment: will it be using the Javascript-Use-API?

Comment: No, the first option is client-side JS. For the second option you could use the Javascript Use API but that’s generally slower and less reliable than the Java Use API.

Comment: how can i add sly tags inside a javascript tag

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to extend the page properties, instead of a component in the body. Then, you can read them directly in the head.html

Comment: I am having an issue of adding <sly> </sly> tags inside a <script></script>

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you share the code sample?