# when appending object to <head/> through javascript it appends two of the same twice

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

i'm messing around with react and for some reason this google fonts and font awesome are added twice, always ,and sometimes even more . But this console log only happens once , i tried creating an element and appending child but it happens the same, how could i solve this?

```
  document.head.innerHTML += `<!-- GOOGLE FONTS --> ${styleData.fontImport} <!-- font-awesome --> 
${styleData.fontAwesome}`;
  console.log("test");
```

i tried every js method on this post [How to add anything in <head> through jquery/javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900874/how-to-add-anything-in-head-through-jquery-javascript)

Comment: `document.head.innerHTML +=` by using `+=` you are making it so that the whole contents get created again not just what you added. So if you had a `<script>` in there previously it will recreate a new one. Use [`.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) to only add new html without recreating previous elements

Comment: when i deployed , the problem wasn't there ... so that's it i guess haha .
 i liked that '.insertAdjacentHTML()' very cool

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append to  tag, please you element.append('only addition tag you want to add')
It will appear the code one time only.

[Source form MDN Web Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append)

```js
let contents = document.head.innerHTML;

document.head.append(`<!-- GOOGLE FONTS --> ${styleData.fontImport} <!-- font-awesome --> 
${styleData.fontAwesome}`);
```

Comment: it's probably some bug at my code... this also gave the result twice, and this method inserted a string in the <head/> and not  Elements.

Comment: An element is a part of a webpage. In XML and HTML, an element may contain a data item or a chunk of text or an image, or perhaps nothing. A typical element includes an opening tag with some attributes, enclosed text content, and a closing tag.

Comment: exactly... the object is referring to the google fonts import through link... anyways i will post it at github this week , its just a small bug nothing major tbh

Comment: i'm back years later to say two things, it was adding twice because of react in strict mode, and it also was outside useEffect so it would never work properly